# How to use Distinct in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have such a table

```
ID     Number    Name
1        55      Jason
2        55      Tiffany
3        66      Joshua
4        66      Tim
5        77      Robert
```

In this table I want records with unique Number, I mean I want to get Jason, Joshua and Robert only. I know there is a `Distinct()` query in LINQ but I don't think that's what I want. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: How do you determine which to select between the two with matching numbers?

Comment: Why choose Jason over Tiffany and Joshua over Tim?

Comment: @maccettura It doesn't matter. I only want one record, it can be Jason or Tiffany.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<yourclass> distinct =
   yourlist
  .GroupBy(item => item.Number)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this query more efficient? It's taking too long to execute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var newList = yourlist.Select(item => item.Number).Distinct()
              .Select(number => yourlist.First(item => item.Number == number)).ToList();
```